# Is Master Chief a human or some sort of robot/alien?

Tags: halo-4

In the Halo trilogy, Master Chiefs face is never shown. I think he's human at least but I'm not quite sure.

I have searched online but nothing really answered my question. Does anyone know what he looks like or if he's even human? Or is he an elite/robot/cyborg? I know Dr.Halsey created or trained him as revealed at the end of the first season of spartan ops.

Comment: Lore by Eric Nylund: Halo: The Fall of Reach = Master Chief's officially supported/licensed prologue

Answer (score 24):

Master Chief, Spartan 117, is human. His name is John (no last name is ever given). He was a citizen of the colonies that was kidnapped at age 6, and taken to train for the military (in secret). In his teen years, he received a series of injections that augmented his physical capabilities to above and beyond what any normal human would ever be able to do. Yet he, and all the other Spartans, remain human.

So why not show his face? Well, that actually stems from how Bungie wanted to approach the character. Master Chief was always meant to be someone you could imagine yourself being. They never intended to reveal who Master Chief was, or show his face, because they felt it betrayed their fans ability to place themselves into the character. Now that 343 has taken over, though, we'll have to see where they go with things, and what they decide to do in the future.

Comment: It's actually kinda similar to how Valve treats Gordon Freeman. Although his appearance is now known as that of a caucassian male wearing glasses, he is never *ever* shown ingame, nor does he ever speak. Even if you manage to see his body's 3D model using cheats in Half-Life 1, his head is covered by a helmet (makes sense, since he's carrying a HazMat suit). Yet he is beyond any doubt human.

Comment: The beginning of Halo 4 hints towards _Who And What_ Master Chief is.

Comment: Technically speaking, he is a forerunner.

Answer (score 4):

He is a human because if you finish the campain on legendary you see his forehead and its human + you see him as a kid in the opening scene.

Comment: thanks, they didn't show this in heroic. also i didn't know the kid was him so thanks.

Comment: no problem your welcome

Answer (score 2):

John-117 "Master Chief" was a human, but after going through the spartan program he is no longer marked as a human but as a "spartan supersoldier"

Master Chief was a light skinned with red/brown hair with freckles when he entered spartan training, but As he is now always in armor pretty much, his hair became white and thin, as well as his skin becoming ghostly pale. during Halo 1 and 2 Bungie wanted their hero to be faceless and without personality so he is "easier to get into", However, as the series grew. books were written (official), and other adaptations (movies, anime, comics, etc) gave Chief and the rest of the universe their own personality.

I suggest reading "The Fall of Reach" book. It explains the backstory very well and gives some insight to the spartan program.

here is some more source and reading from the off the wiki about John-117. [click me](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/John-117)

Answer (score 0):

I remember in Halo 4 the Librarian was telling him that he was sorta a mix of human/forerunner and he was carrying the seed of the forerunner that created the Halo. Ik im pretty late but i was watching halo 4 and i noticed that the 2nd time i listened to it

Answer (score 0):

One of the cadets calls him a giant robot in the Halo 4 movie

Answer (score -3):

I think master chief is an alien because after doing some research online I saw master chiefs face in the newest halo coming out on December 31st Halo 5 and his face does not resemble a human, I also watched a video and master chief is on an alien planet as a child and in the video it says master chiefs kind or civilization was taken out at this point I dont know who or what had taken his kind out. In the same video Dr. Hulsey comes up to him flips a coin and master chief catches it and asks him to call it master chief calls eagle and it was indeed tales and my point here is that master chief is in fact an alien who has knowledge of the human race and luck or fate on his side.

Comment: If [that's the face you're talking about](http://th07.deviantart.net/fs70/PRE/f/2012/341/9/9/john___117_by_rexadde-d5luhag.jpg), then it looks very human to me.

Comment: This is very, very wrong.